# Using cursor or while loop or any other way?

Tags: sql-server-2008, stored-procedures, cursor, while-loop, recordset

I've gone through several discussions related (not exact) to this but I want to know the correct solution to my situation hence posting this question.

I need to select some records from a table based on some condition and pass each record values to a SP.

I thought of using Cursor to loop through the record set, after some googling I found while loop is also used and many discussions on which one is best are there and most of them said that it depends on the situation. Now I'm not able to judge my situation hence putting in front of experts.

Here is the while loop I thought of:

```
Table Test
{
  id int
  value int
  -- Some more fields
}

WHILE EXISTS(SELECT TOP 1 id FROM Test WHERE isValid=1)
BEGIN
  DECLARE @id AS INT
  DECLARE @value AS INT
  SELECT TOP 1 @id=id, @value=value FROM Test WHERE isValid=1
  EXEC SP_SomeProcessingSP @id, @value -- Some more fields passed to it from above table
  -- After execution of the above SP I need to update the record to invalid
  UPDATE Test SET isValid = 0 WHERE id=@id
END
```

Is this approach better than cursor? It would be great if anyone can come up with better solution without while and cursor (I want to avoid both).

**Edit:** Modified the while block and gave example table as well. Now the SP which is called inside this while block accesses data from couple of tables and do some processing and insert data into couple of other tables.

Comment: You might want to consider using [CLR Stored Procedure](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131094.aspx). I'm not sure about it's pros and cons. May be someone more knowledgeable on it can throw more light.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like a round about way to do:

```
UPDATE Test SET isValid = 0 WHERE isValid = 1
```

As for what approach is best, you have not supplied enough detail for an answer.

It entirely depends on what you are trying to do. Perhaps a recursive CTE would solve your problems without the need to call a stored procedure. Perhaps a good join would solve it. Perhaps a different solution would be best.

You need to explain what *exactly* you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Ooops you mis understood my question. You missed my comment block between select and update statment. I'll be calling another SP with the values got from select statement.

Comment: @JPReddy - No, I didn't. It is simply not enough information.

Comment: I've updated my question to give some more information. I hope that information is enough, please let me know if you need more.

Comment: @JPReddy - It depends on what the SP does. It is possible that you can simply pass in the whole list of IDs to the stored procedure in one go. In general, it is better to use set operations (joins, unions etc...) instead of loops of any kind.

Comment: Got your point, cant do such thing. Because that is an existing SP and I've to use it. Looks like I've to go with While or Cursor

Answer (score 0):

You could modify the stored procedure to take tables as inputs and then select into a table variable.  For the update you can join back on that table variable.

Check out Table Valued Parameters here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510489.aspx